# Determinant-preserving mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, finite-fields, matrix-rank

It's known that, if $K$ is an infinite field, every linear mapping $T : \mathcal M_n(K) \rightarrow \mathcal M_n(K)$ which preserves determinant also preserves rank. 
I'm wondering if it is still true for a finite field.

Thank you for your help, Marcin

PS. We have $\det(T(M))=\det(M)$ for all $M\in \mathcal M_n(K)$ and I'm asking if $\mathrm{rg}(T(M))=\mathrm{rg}(M)$.

Comment: Maybe https://mathoverflow.net/questions/522/linear-transformation-that-preserves-the-determinant answers this question.